How to redirect to the home page from a page under the Areas folder?
I'm trying to redirect to my home page from a page under the Areas folder.
I tried:
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return RedirectToPage("/");
}

But this throws an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No page named '/' matches the supplied values.'

I found this question, and it recommended:
return RedirectToPage("/Index");

But this seemed to take me to the Index in the current folder.
I also tried this:
return RedirectToPage("~/Index");

But this also throws an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No page named '~/Index' matches the supplied values.'

And the same error with:
return RedirectToPage("~/");

So how can I redirect to the home page from a page under the Areas folder?

Finally figured out the answer.
return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "" });

I found it rather non-intuitive.

I'm not an expert but googling a bit I find this one:
If your proyect it's MVC try with:
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

If your proyect it's Razor, try with:
return Redirect("~/");

and you might be redirected to the homepage.
Good luck
